# Synthesize Properties From Other Views?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This question is more of an abstract to understand how multiple views interact.

Take the following scenario-

**view1.h**

-> `#import "view2.h"`

-> `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *variableA;`

**view1.m**

-> `@synthesize variableA, variableB`

**view2.h**

-> `#import "view1.h"`

-> `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *variableB;`

**view2.m**

-> `@synthesize variableA, variableB`

Why doesn't this work?  Do I need to import the other view's header into the implementation file as well?  Is there a different way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Why are you trying to synthesise a property of another class. That's totally weird. Synthesising generates the accessors for the property which are the responsibility of the class that it belongs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the use of `@synthesize`. Effectively, its only purpose now is to allow local access to the property's ivar through a specified name. For example:

```
@interface View1 : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *variableA;
@end

@implementation View1
@synthesize variableA;
- (void)someMethod {
  NSLog(@"%@", variableA);
}
@end
```

Compare to no `@synthesize`:

```
@interface View2 : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *variableB;
@end

@implementation View2
- (void)someMethod {
  NSLog(@"%@", _variableA);
  NSLog(@"%@", self.variableA);
}
@end
```

If you want to access a property from a different class or a subclass, use either the selector or dot notation.

```
@interface View3 : View1
- (void)anotherMethod:(View2 *)view1;
@end

@implementation View3
- (void)anotherMethod:(View2 *)view2 {
  NSLog(@"%@", self.variableA);
  NSLog(@"%@", [self variableA]);
  NSLog(@"%@", view2.variableB);
  NSLog(@"%@", [view2 variableB]);
}
@end
```

Comment: Ahh.  Yes.  selector or dot notation.  That's exactly what I'm looking for.  Thank you

Comment: There is also the less popular pointer notation: `view2->_variableB`, but I really really don't suggest using it. Just know that it's available in a pinch.